# How to import submodule into parent namespace?

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I have a directory structure like this:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    printsum.py
        '''
        def printsum(x,y):
            print("sum is " + str(x+y))
        '''
bar.py
    '''
    def printsum(x,y):
        print("sum is " + str(x+y))
    '''
example.py
    '''
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import foo.printsum
    import bar


    foo.printsum.printsum(1,2)
    bar.printsum(3,4)
    '''
```

The file `example.py` is meant to be run as a script, while `foo` and `bar` are meant to be imported modules. I would like to make the namespace of `foo` like `bar`. That is - I don't want the double `printsum.printsum`. I don't want *all* of the `foo` module to be saved in one big monolithic file, like `bar.py`. I want the `foo.printsum()` method to be saved in a file by itself, but I want `printsum()` to exist at the `foo.` namespace level.

Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the functions in `__init__py`.

foo/__init__py:

```
from .printsum import printsum
```

(If you are using python2, you might need to remove the dot or use full import path. Rules for relative import paths are stricter in python 3)

Then you can call the function directly from foo:

```
import foo
foo.printsum(...)
```

The `foo` import will run `__init__`. You can add some prints in there as well if you want proof. This is a perfectly normal way to expose functionality in package modules. You can also do * imports, but that is generally not recommended. Import strictly what you want to expose.

`__init__` in other words is a place you can glue stuff to the package, but also do automatic initialisation that triggers in the import.

Also look up the `__all__` keyword. It can be extremely useful to hide code that is not relevant for a user of the package or module.